# Authorize.net :: Sandbox :: Error:: Transaction Status: Declined (Card declined by issuer - Contact card issuer to determine reason.)

Tags: authorize.net

I am testing authorize.net using sandbox account and using the credit card details from http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/

But it says the error message:

> Transaction Status:   Declined  (Card declined by issuer - Contact card issuer to determine reason.)

Update :

url used : https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"

Answer (score -1):

This happens for two reasons:

1. You are using the sandbox and use special payment values that trigger a decline for testing purposes (i.e. using zip code 46282)
2. You are not using a sandbox account and are using a live account and the credit card you are using is not valid so you get a decline message

Based on the information you have provided scenario #2 is likely the cause of your problem. Make sure you are using the developer/sandbox URL and credentials for your testing.

Comment: It was working fine previously, but now only it throws this error, I dont have live account. and I used the test url only

Comment: Downvoting because I'm definitely using a sandbox account, and not triggering a decline, and I am getting this error msg

Comment: Same here; Im using a sandbox account, and no matter what Zip code I use, the transaction goes successful . CC types works fine when changed .